# How can I make a cascading dropdown list?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have Companies and Vacancies tables.

Company has n number of Vacancies. I need to make two dropdown lists.

In one it will be Company, when I select it, there will be Vacancies related to this company.

Here is model of Companies

```
 public Company()
    {
        this.Clients = new HashSet<Client>();
        this.Vacancies = new HashSet<Vacancy>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int CompanyID { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public virtual AspNetUser AspNetUser { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Client> Clients { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Vacancy> Vacancies { get; set; }
}
```

Here is model for Vacancies

```
 public partial class Vacancy
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Vacancy()
    {
        this.Interviews = new HashSet<Interview>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int VacancyId { get; set; }
    public string VacancyName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> CompanyID { get; set; }

    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Interview> Interviews { get; set; }
```

Here is controller where I need to do this

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult WelcomeScreen()
    {
        // Формируем список команд для передачи в представление
        SelectList teams = new SelectList(db.Vacancy, "VacancyId", "VacancyName");
        ViewBag.Teams = teams;

        return View();
    }


    //Заносим инфу о вакансии в таблицу
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult WelcomeScreen(Interview interview)
    {
        db.Interview.Add(interview);
        db.SaveChanges();
        //Int32 id = interview.Interview_Id;
        //TempData["id"] = id;

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Questions", new { id = interview.Interview_Id });
    }
```

How I need to make Cascade Dropdown list?

**UPDATE**

I try solution

Here is my  controller (Questions controller)

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult WelcomeScreen()
    {
        // Формируем список команд для передачи в представление
        //SelectList teams = new SelectList(db.Vacancy, "VacancyId", "VacancyName");
        //ViewBag.Teams = teams;

        ViewBag.Companies = new SelectList(db.Companies, "CompanyID", "CompanyName");
        return View();
    }


    //Заносим инфу о вакансии в таблицу
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult WelcomeScreen(Interview interview)
    {
        db.Interview.Add(interview);
        db.SaveChanges();
        //Int32 id = interview.Interview_Id;
        //TempData["id"] = id;

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Questions", new { id = interview.Interview_Id });
    }
    public ActionResult Vacancies(int companyId)
    {
        var items = db.Vacancy
                      .Where(x => x.CompanyID == companyId)
                      .Select(x => new SelectListItem
                      {
                          Value = x.VacancyId.ToString(),
                          Text = x.VacancyName
                      })
                      .ToList();
        return Json(items, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Here is script

```
 <script>
    $(function () {
        $("#Company").change(function (e) {
            var $vacancy = $("#vacancy");
            var url = $vacancy.data("url") + '?companyId=' + $(this).val();
            $.getJSON(url, function (items) {
                $.each(items, function (a, b) {
                    $vacancy.append('<option value="' + b.Value + '">' + b.Text + '</option>');
                });
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

And here is View

```
 <div class="right-grid-in-grid">

                <div style="margin-left:20px;">
                    @Html.DropDownList("Company", ViewBag.Companies as SelectList, new { @class =  "greeting"})
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.VacancyId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>

                <div style="margin-left:20px;">
                    <select name="id" id="vacancy" data-url="@Url.Action("Vacancies","Questions")" class="greeting"/>
                </div>
                </div>
```

But AJAX not works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of cascading dropdown is, When you load the page, you load the dropdown content for the first SELECT element. The second SELECT element will be an empty one. When user selects an option from the first dropdown, send that to the server which returns the content needed to build the second dropdown.

So in the GET action of your page, get the data needed to render the first dropdown.

```
public ActionResult Welcome()
{
  ViewBag.Companies = new SelectList(db.Companies, "CompanyID", "CompanyName");
  return View();
}
```

Now in the view, you can use the DropDownList helper method to render the SELECT element with the data we set to the ViewBag.Companies. We will also add our second dropdown as well.

```
@Html.DropDownList("Company", ViewBag.Companies as SelectList)
<select name="id" id="vacancy" data-url="@Url.Action("Vacancies","Home")">
```

Now we will use some ajax code(*using jQuery in this example*) to get the content for the second dropdown. Register an event handler for the `change` event of the first dropdown, get the selected value, make an ajax call to the Vacancies action method which returns the data needed to build the second dropdown in JSON format. Use this JSON data to build the second dropdown in javascript.

```
$(function(){
    $("#Company").change(function (e) {
        var $vacancy = $("#vacancy");
        var url = $vacancy.data("url")+'?companyId='+$(this).val();
        $.getJSON(url, function (items) {
            $.each(items, function (a, b) {
                $vacancy.append('<option value="' + b.Value + '">' + b.Text + '</option>');
            });
        });
    });    
});
```

Now the last part is, implementing the Vacancies method.

```
public ActionResult Vacancies(int companyId)
{
    var items = db.Vacancies
                  .Where(x=>x.CompanyID==comapnyId)
                  .Select(x => new SelectListItem { Value = x.VacancyId.ToString(),
                                                    Text = x.VacancyName })
                  .ToList();
    return Json(items, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Assuming `db` is your DbContext class object.

*Ajax is not necessary for implementing cascading dropdowns. You can post the form with the selected companyId and the action method can return the same with second dropdown filled. But people usually use ajax to give a nice user experience*

Comment: I tried code, but my second list isn't have any values

Comment: is it making the ajax call when you do a selection on first dropdown ? Check the network tab in browser dev tools

Comment: Checked, seems like it didn't do any requests

Comment: Are you sure the `change` event is being called ? I hope you are using the correct Ids to bind the events

Comment: I have one small question. For Vacancy I need to save id to table how I can do this now?