# Is there a way to change the values of a @Html.DropDownList from a previous selection in another drop down list in asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I having an issue where I would like to change The value of a @Html.DropDownList that would change the values in the following @Html.DropDownList.

this is my logic: I have 2 lists

```
@{ 
     List<SelectListItem> CarMake = new List<SelectListItem>();
     CarMake.Add(new SelectListItem {Text="Acura", Value ="Acura" });
     CarMake.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Honda", Value = "Honda" });

     List<SelectListItem> CarModel = new List<SelectListItem>();
     CarModel.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Civic", Value = "Civic" });
     CarModel.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "RL", Value = "RL" });
}
```

this is my View:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Car name</label>
    @Html.DropDownList("Car make" ,CarMake, "Select", new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Car model</label>
    @Html.DropDownList("Car make", CarModel, "Select", new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
```

so what I want to do is If **CarMake** "Acura" is selected then only **CarModel** "RL" will be displayed in the second dropDownList. This was much easier to do in webforms since there was a selectedindexchanged. Is there a simple elegant way to do this in MVC?

Comment: See this cascading dropdown sample [Make Cascade dropdown List (ASP.NET MVC)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43031292/make-cascade-dropdown-list-asp-net-mvc/43031665#43031665)

Comment: Here's another example with 2 DDL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28627421/better-way-to-load-2-dropdown-in-mvc.

Comment: Refer also [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bPZym)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all the commentators that really helped out but im going to answer my question.

what i did was create class called CarMake that had to classes shown bellow called Category and product with some propeties.

```
namespace hiophop.Models
{
    public class CarMake
    {
        public class Category
        {
            public int CategoryID { get; set; }
            public string CategoryName { get; set; }

        }

        public class Product
        {
            public int ProductID { get; set; }
            public string ProductName { get; set; }
            public int CategoryID { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

then in my controller I populated the lists and made with the CategoryID properties in both values I made them equal each other lstCat.CategoryID == lstprod.CategoryID in the fields that they where needed category 1 is toyota thus toyota models. I used  JsonRequestBehavior and linq to help me achieve  passing of my required data to the view.

```
public class CarController : Controller
{
    List<Category> lstCat = new List<Category>()
    {
        new Category() { CategoryID = 1, CategoryName = "Toyota" },
        new Category() { CategoryID = 2, CategoryName = "Honda" },
        new Category() { CategoryID = 3, CategoryName = "Chevy" }
    };

    List<Product> lstProd = new List<Product>()
    {
        new Product() { ProductID = 1, ProductName = "camry", CategoryID = 1 },
        new Product() { ProductID = 2, ProductName = "rav4", CategoryID = 1 },
        new Product() { ProductID = 3, ProductName = "accord", CategoryID = 1 },
        new Product() { ProductID = 4, ProductName = "civic", CategoryID = 2 },
        new Product() { ProductID = 5, ProductName = "fit", CategoryID = 2 },
        new Product() { ProductID = 6, ProductName = "vue", CategoryID = 2 },
        new Product() { ProductID = 7, ProductName = "malibu", CategoryID = 3 },
        new Product() { ProductID = 8, ProductName = "impala", CategoryID = 3 },
        new Product() { ProductID = 9, ProductName = "iroc", CategoryID = 3 }
    };

    public ActionResult GetCategories()
    {
        return Json(lstCat, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }

    public ActionResult GetProducts(int intCatID)
    {
        var products = lstProd.Where(p => p.CategoryID == intCatID);
        return Json(products, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string category ,string product)
    {


        ViewBag.x ="Product"+ product;
        ViewBag.y = "catego" + category;
        return View();
    }
}
```

Then in my view I made made wrote this and it worked

```
 @ViewBag.y
@ViewBag.x


@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Car", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div>
        <label for="category">Category</label>
        <select id="category" name="c" class="form-control"></select>
        <label for="product">Product</label>
        <select id="product" name="p"  class="form-control"></select>



        <input type="submit" id="Button" class="btn btn-default" />




    </div>
}
@section scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            // Get a list of categories and a list of products of the first category.
            $.getJSON('/Car/GetCategories', null, function (data) {
                $.each(data, function () {
                    $('#category').append('<option value=' +
                      this.CategoryID + '>' + this.CategoryName + '</option>');
                });
                $.getJSON('/Car/GetProducts', { intCatID: $('#category').val() }, function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function () {
                        $('#product').append('<option value=' +
                          this.ProductID + '>' + this.ProductName + '</option>');

                    });
                }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert('Error getting products!');
                });
            }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('Error getting categories!');
            });

            // Dropdown list change event.
            $('#category').change(function () {
                $('#product option').remove();
                $.getJSON('/Car/GetProducts', { intCatID: $('#category').val() }, function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function () {
                        $('#product').append('<option value=' +
                          this.ProductID + '>' + this.ProductName + '</option>');
                    });
                }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert('Error getting products!');
                });
            });
        });







        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#Button1").click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                    url: '/Car/Index',
                    data: "{'Category':'" + document.getElementById('#category') + "','product':'" + document.getElementById('#product') + " '}",
                    async: false,
                    success: function (response) {
                        $('#category').val('');
                        $('#product').val('');

                        alert("record has been saved in database");

                    },
                    error: function () {
                        console.log('there is some error');
                    }

                });

            });

        });
    </script>
}
```

in my controller it gets the values of  in post and return

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string category ,string product)
    {


        ViewBag.x ="Product"+ product;
        ViewBag.y = "catego" + category;
        return View();
    }
```

This retrieves the index number value location of the CategoryID and ProductID in the controller above and passes it through the viewbag. I trying to work on how to pass the text value now.