# How to bind dropdown list in ASP.NET MVC from SQL Server database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I don't know how to make view from this code to show data in dropdown list. Please do tell me what changes I can make to solve my problem. I have tried some view but this causes errors.

Model:

```
public class Cities
{
    public int cityid { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Dropdownlist()
{
    List<Citites> cityname= new List<Citites>();
    string constring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbx"].ConnectionString;

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring);

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Cityid, Description FROM Cities", con);

    con.Open();

    SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        Citites ci = new Citites();
        ci.cityid = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["Cityid"]);
        ci.Description = rdr[1].ToString();                
        cityname.Add(ci);
    }

    return View(cityname);
}
```

View:

```
@model IEnumerable< RegisterForm_crud_mvc_.Models.Citites>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Dropdownlist";
}

<h2>Dropdownlist</h2>

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.cityid, Model.citynanme)
```

Comment: @Igor Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.cityid, Model.citynanme) i have tried it but this give error

Comment: `i have tried it but this give error` <= [We need ALL Exception details to help you](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/). Also post that code (the code from your view template)

Comment: @Igor i have edited u can check. my problem is to show city name in dropdown list from data base just it.

Answer (score 2):

You have a bunch of issues in your code. Your view is strongly typed to a list of City objects and you are trying to use  `Model.citynanme`. Your model is the list of city object and the list does not have a cityname property ( but each item in the list has)!

What you should ideally do is , Create a view model to represent the data needede in your view. In your case, you need a property to store the selected option value and another for data needed to build the options for the SELECT element. In your case it is the list of cities.

```
public class MyViewModel
{
  public List<SelectListItem> Cities { set;get;}
  public int SelectedCityId { set;get;}
}
```

Now in your GET action, you create an object of this, populate the Cities property by reading your table and send the view model object to the view.

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
  var vm = new MyViewModel();
  vm.Cities = GetCities();
  return View(vm);
}
private List<SelectListItem> GetCities()
{
    var options = new List<SelectListItem>();
    var constring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbx"].ConnectionString;
    using (var c = new SqlConnection(constring))
    {
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("select Cityid, Description FROM Cities", c))
        {
            c.Open();
            var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            options = new List<SelectListItem>();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                var o = new SelectListItem
                {
                    Value = rdr.GetInt32(rdr.GetOrdinal("Cityid")).ToString(),
                    Text = rdr.GetString(rdr.GetOrdinal("Description"))
                };
                options.Add(o);
            }
        }
    }
    return options;
}
```

Now in your view, which is strongly typed to MyViewModel, you will use `Html.DropDownListfor` helper method where you will use the `Cities` property as the selectList parameter.

```
@model MyViewModel
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedCityId, Model.Cities)
```

Comment: thanks u very much brother its working.but i have a question does it work for cascading dropdown list.change the town on the base of city valu?and then use for crud operation.if so plz do guide me.

Comment: You listen to the `change` event of the first dropdown, read the selected value and send to your server and have some server code which gets the filtered data and send back to the client. In your ajax call's success event, iterate through the json array and build a li element and add tot he second dropdown. Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43031292/make-cascade-dropdown-list-asp-net-mvc/43031665#43031665

Comment: the link u mention is contain ajax .i dnt knw even a b of ajax.could u tell me another without ajax and jqurey eta.